# Accessing the HTMLElement of a marker's icon in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have some markers with custom icons (DivIcons) on my map.

**When I click on one marker, I want to access to the HTMLElement of the icon, to add or remove classes.**

The only way I have found to access the HTMLElement is the `_icon` property. I understand it's a private property, but I can't find another way.

The `options.icon` returns me the icon object (used by many markers), not the concrete HTMLElement for this marker.

Do you know a safe way to access to the HTMLElement of a marker ?

Comment: Don't see any problems using `_icon` property. Why do you hesitate to use it?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr, unfortunately it looks like a private field (start with _).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a documented way to access it :

Since I am in a "click" event, I can access the marker's HTMLElement with `event.originalEvent.target` in the callback.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects

Comment: Nope ! `event.originalEvent.target` !

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have native support for private properties. However, there are several techniques to emulate them: one using prefixes, the other closures.

The use of an underscore prefix is just a coding convention and is not enforced by the language: there is nothing to prevent a user from directly accessing a property that is "supposed to be private". This method is not safe, and it serves only as a guideline for client code. So I don't think that any harm can be done by accessing `_icon` property.

If a property is supposed to be private without possibility to be accessed from the outside, it is usually set as a local variable of a certain scope without being binded to the context. This type of variables can be accessed from the outside only with the help of closures, and if they are not defined, the variable can't be accessed.

Comment: I know it's only a convention, but since there is not documentation about this property, I wanted to be sure this property will not disapear in a next version.
By the way, for now I am using it, and it's perfectly what I need.